# Are there functions such that $\frac{d^{n}f(x)}{dx^{n}}$=$f^{n}(x)$, that is $f\circ (f\circ (f\circ (f\cdots\circ (f(x))$ for any $n\geq2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen questions involving finding functions such that the $n^{th}$ derivative is equal to $f^{-1}$ or something similar. As a challenge and a puzzle to keep me occupied, I wondered if there were any functions which satisfied $\frac{d^{n}f(x)}{dx^{n}}$=$f\circ (f\circ (f\circ (f\cdots\circ (f(x))$ where $f$ is composed with itself $n$ times. I've talked with some people and at the very least, restricting the function to be both locally analytic and have a compact and convex domain and codomain is too strong and it turns out no such function exists. Merely having a function be locally analytic doesn't appear to be enough either though as most of the typical functions like trig functions, logarithms, etc. don't seem to work as solutions at least at first glance.

Any potential insights into this would be much appreciated. Whilst there probably isn't a satisfying clean answer to this,I definitely don't have the knowledge to solve this on my own.

Comment: I think you mean $n \geq 2$ and not $n > 2$. Also put this in your question and not just in the title.

Comment: Do you mean $f^n$ as $f(x)^n$ or do you mean $f\circ f\circ \cdots\circ f$ ($n$ times)

Comment: I meant $f$ composed with itself $n$ times, not exponentiation, sorry for not exactly being clear. Yeah, I did mean n$\geq$2

Answer (score 1):

$$f^{n+1} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f = \frac{d}{dx}  f^{n} = n \frac{d}{dx} f f^{n-1}$$
Thus, for all n :
$$f^2 = n f' $$
So $$f = 0$$.

Comment: It looks like you're taking the derivative of the $n$th power of $f$, but the OP says $f^n$ means the $n$th iterate.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry. The problem is trickier then.